Que es mejor usar los usuarios de mysql o crear una tabla usuarios en la base de datos?
Bueno mi problema es que tengo un proyecto escolar que va a ser una plataforma para que los profesores inicien sesión y realicen ciertas actividades, mi duda en concreto va sobre que debo usar para el inicio de sesión si los usuarios de mysql que se crean con la sentencia CREATE USER o crear una tabla de usuarios en mi esquema de base de datos, he visto información sobre como hacerlo con ambas pero no una explicación de el por que usar una o la otra opción.

si tu aplicacion tendra login y creacion de usuarios es mejor por tabla!

Si tu aplicación escolar implica la gestión de usuarios que interactúan con la plataforma (por ejemplo, profesores que inician sesión para realizar actividades), definitivamente sería más apropiado crear una tabla de usuarios en la base de datos para gestionarlos de manera eficiente y escalable.
La sentencia CREATE USER se utiliza para crear usuarios que pueden acceder directamente a la base de datos, lo cual tiene un propósito diferente al de gestionar usuarios de la aplicación.

a ok entonces tabla para aplicación y usuario de mysql para interactuar directamente con la base, entendido muchas gracias.
